# Least Squares with $ {L}_{2} $ (L2) Linear Norm Regularization (Not Squared)

Tags: convex-optimization, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

Define $$L(w,u)=\frac{1}{2}\|w-u\|^2+\beta \left\|\frac{w}{x}\right\|,~w,u\in \Bbb{R}^n$$
where $$\frac{w}{x}=\left(\frac{w_1}{x_1},\ldots, \frac{w_n}{x_n}\right)$$
$$\|x\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$$
Given $u$, $x$ and $\beta$, how to get $$\arg\min_{w\in \Bbb{R}^n}L(w,u)$$

Comment: Taking derivative gives $w - u + 2\beta\frac{w}{x^{\circ 2}}$ and second derivative is semi-definite. Therefore, setting the derivative to zero should give you a local minimum.

Comment: @TenaliRaman, You remark isn't right. This is not the derivative (The above is not the squared norm but the norm itself).

Comment: @Royi +1 yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be defining $ X = \operatorname{diag} \left( \frac{1}{ {x}_{1} }, \frac{1}{ {x}_{2} }, \ldots , \frac{1}{ {x}_{n} } \right) $.

Then the problem becomes:

$$ \arg \min_{w} \frac{1}{2} \left\| w - u \right\|_{2}^{2} + \beta \left\| X w \right\|_{2} $$

Now, remember that $ \nabla_{x} \left\| x \right\|_{2} = \frac{x}{ \left\| x \right\|_{2} } $ then the derivative is given by:

$$ w - u + \beta {X}^{T} \frac{X w}{ \left\| X w \right\|_{2} } $$

with some tweaking:

$$ w = \left( \frac{\beta}{\left\| X w \right\|_{2}} {X}^{T} X + I \right)^{-1} u $$

Now you can use the [Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) (IRLS) Approach to calculate $ w $ and since the problem is Convex you'll get your solution.

Pay attention that $ \frac{\beta}{\left\| X w \right\|_{2}} {X}^{T} X + I $ is diagonal hence the inversion is easy.

MATLAB Code:

```
hObjFun = @(vW) (0.5 * sum((vW - vU) .^ 2)) + (paramBeta * norm(vW ./ vX));

vObjVal = zeros([numIterations, 1]);

vW = vU;
vObjVal(1) = hObjFun(vW);

for ii = 2:numIterations

    % Calculation of the inverse term. Since all diagonlas terms can be
    % done using vectors.
    fctrTerm    = paramBeta / norm(vW ./ vX);
    vXX         = (1 ./ (vX .^ 2));
    vInvXX      = 1 ./ ((fctrTerm * vXX) + ones([numRows, 1]));

    vW = vInvXX .* vU;

    vObjVal(ii) = hObjFun(vW);
end

disp([' ']);
disp(['Iterative Reweighted Least Squares (IRLS) Solution Summary']);
disp(['The Optimal Value Is Given By - ', num2str(vObjVal(numIterations))]);
disp(['The Optimal Argument Is Given By - [ ', num2str(vW.'), ' ]']);
disp([' ']);
```

The code take advantage of all matrices being diagonal and hence the operations can be element wise which makes the code very simple and efficient.

[image]

As can be seen above, the convergence is very quick and the code is efficient.

The full MATLAB code is in my [StackExchange Mathematics Q454519 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q454519).

Comment: Pretty solution. Perhaps you could move $X^TX$ outside the loop?

Comment: @JirapatSamranvedhya, Yea. The code can be farther optimized. But since all are vectors all operations are O(n) it won't be dramatic. I preferred keeping it clear to others.

Answer (score 1):

$$
L(w,u)=\frac{1}{2}\|w-u\|^2+\beta \|\frac{w}{x}\| =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n (w_i-u_i)^2+\beta\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{w_i^2}{x_i^2}}
$$
Hint :

> $$
>  \frac{\partial L}{\partial w_k}=w_k-u_k+\beta\frac{w_k/x_k^2}{\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{w_i^2}{x_i^2}}}=0, \qquad k=1,2,\cdots,n $$

Comment: Thanks. But how to solve those equations?